# Google maps fragment in epoxy view

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, androidx, epoxy

I'm currently exploring the new [MvRx](https://github.com/airbnb/MvRx) stack from Airbnb

Rigth now i am adding a google maps fragment successfully to a BaseMvRxFragment in a BottomNavigationView.

The problem is that the 2. time i navigate to the MapFragment my app crashes and i get the following error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: getflareapp.com.s2s, PID: 19184
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f080093, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3752)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:405)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:387)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:23239)
        at getflareapp.com.s2s.views.MapView.<init>(MapView.kt:19)
        at getflareapp.com.s2s.views.MapView.<init>(MapView.kt:14)
        at getflareapp.com.s2s.views.MapView.<init>(Unknown Source:6)
        at getflareapp.com.s2s.views.MapViewModel_.buildView(MapViewModel_.java:42)
        at getflareapp.com.s2s.views.MapViewModel_.buildView(MapViewModel_.java:22)
```

MapFragment.kt

```
/**
 * A simple [BaseFragment] subclass.
 *
 */
class MapFragment : BaseFragment() {


    private val mViewModel: ChatViewModel by fragmentViewModel()

    override fun epoxyController() = simpleController(mViewModel) {state ->


        mapView{
            id("map")
        }
    }

}
```

MapView.kt

```
@ModelView(autoLayout = ModelView.Size.MATCH_WIDTH_MATCH_HEIGHT)
class MapView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        // TODO: Fix crash on second view.
        inflate(context, R.layout.view_map, this)
    }
}
```

view_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map2"
        android:name="getflareapp.com.s2s.ui.map.MapFragment"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.MainActivity" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks for any help! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve problems adding directly the map fragment inner other fragment, so i suggest change that with Framelayout and inflate the fragment manually.